# Do I need Indicators for Regression with Categorical Variables?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lm

It is always said that we need to create predictor variables for categorical values in order to the regression. I made a test, by creating first a predictor column of 1, 2, 3s for a five-layered categorical variable. Then, I ran the same model, without the predictor column, but with the categorical column itself.

In conclusion, the coefficients are different; however, their relative importance and effect on the y-value are the same. Moreover R-squared and p-value numbers are exactly the same in these two cases. So, do I have to create the predictor variable, or is R smart enough to do it automatically?

```
for(i in 1:74)
{
  if(travel$accommodation[i] == "Hotel")
  {
    travel$pred_hotel[i] <- 1
  }

  if(travel$accommodation[i] == "Airbnb")
  {
    travel$pred_hotel[i] <- 2
  }

  if(travel$accommodation[i] == "Hostel")
  {
    travel$pred_hotel[i] <- 3
  }

  if(travel$accommodation[i] == "With friend/family")
  {
    travel$pred_hotel[i] <- 4
  }

  if(travel$accommodation[i] == "Other")
  {
    travel$pred_hotel[i] <- 5
  }
}

travel$pred_hotel <- as.factor(travel$pred_hotel)
```

Then:

```
msf <- lm(ticket_events_money ~ museum_fee + nationality + 
    ticket_events_frequency + accommodation + line + activity_1 + 
    locals + vacation_days, data = travel[-1, ])

mm <- lm(ticket_events_money ~ museum_fee + nationality + 
    ticket_events_frequency + pred_hotel + line + activity_1 + 
    locals + vacation_days, data = travel[-1, ])

summary(msf)
summary(mm)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you originally have a character column `accommodation`. Your new variable `pred_hotel` is a factor. Function `lm` automatically converts character covariate into factor. In your test, the only difference will be in factor levels; all the rest is the same. If you want to see difference, remove the `as.factor` line.

Another common failure is as in the following minimal, reproducible example.

```
dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(20), x = rep(letters[1:2], 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, dat)

dat$x[dat$x == 'a'] <- 1
dat$x[dat$x == 'b'] <- 2
class(dat$x)    # still a character column!!
m2 <- lm(y ~ x, dat)
```

But you will see difference, if you use real numeric:

```
dat$x <- as.numeric(dat$x)
m3 <- lm(y ~ x, dat)
```